# Bash test command with 2 conditions

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm trying to execute a bash test command with 2 conditions.

`test "4" = "4" && "5" = "5" || echo "false"`

I'm expecting it to *not* print false since both conditions are true. But what I'm actually getting is this:

```
5: command not found 
false
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I recommend `[[ "4" = "4" && "5" = "5" ]]` instead of the not working `test "4" = "4" && "5" = "5"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` goes between commands and combines their statuses. Your second command is just

```
"5" = "5"
```

which tries to run `5` as a command.

You need to repeat `test`.

```
test "4" = "4" && test "5" = "5" || echo "false"
```

You can also use the `-a` operator of the `test` command:

```
test "4" = "4" -a "5" = "5" || echo "false"
```

But this is not recommended; this operator is deprecated because it can be ambiguous in some cases.

Comment: `-a` (along with `-o`) is typically not recommended as it is [deprecated](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and has poorly defined behavior in more complex conditions.